# How to Alternate Geometry Layouts With \atbegshi

Tags: geometry, layout, atbegshi, shipout, everyshi

## ... A documentation question ...

**Question:** Is `\AtBeginShipoutNext` from the `atbegshi` package  intended to "exceptionally" apply to a single printed page?  Or, would this not even work with the `geometry` package?

**A Strange Use Case:** Geometry margins, (headers, etc.), need to change vertical heights because watermark illustrations alternate sizes every other page. (Would like to use the `atbegshi` features for foreground and background boxes in the headers ...

I am just trying to reset Geometry, (`\newgeometry`) with hooks.  I have been trying to do this with those packages - but I am not even sure they will support that.

## Just trying to toggle Header on and off, in this example.

***Note:*** Preferably without using `\thispagestyle`. I am trying to understand how this works, low level.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[showframe, vdivide={0.75in,*,0.75in}, includeall, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
% **********************
% **********************
% **********************
\newcommand{\SetDefaultGeometry}{%
    \newgeometry{%
        headheight=0em,
        headsep=0em,
        footskip=0em
    }
    \savegeometry{DefaultGeometry}
}
% **********************
% **********************
% **********************
\newcommand{\SetChapterPageGeometry}{%
    \newgeometry{%
        headheight=3em,
        headsep=3em    
    }
    \savegeometry{ChapterPageGeometry}
}

% **********************
% **********************
% **********************
\newcommand{\SetChapterTitleGeometry}{%
    \newgeometry{%
        %\NewFluidGeometry{%        
        headheight=0em,
        headsep=0em
    }
    \savegeometry{ChapterTitleGeometry}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\EveryShipoutHook}{}
\newcommand{\NextShipoutHook}{}

\newcommand{\BeginShipoutHook}{}
\newcommand{\BeginShipoutNextHook}{}

\AtBeginShipout{\BeginShipoutHook}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{\BeginShipoutNextHook}

\EveryShipout{\EveryShipoutHook}
\AtNextShipout{\NextShipoutHook}


\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\BeginShipoutNextHook}{\SetChapterPageGeometry}
%\renewcommand{\BeginShipoutHook}{\SetChapterPageGeometry}
\SetChapterTitleGeometry
\LARGE{Testing1}
\par \blindtext
\SetChapterPageGeometry
%\renewcommand{\NextShipoutHook}{\SetPageGeometry}
\blindtext \pagebreak \blindtext \clearpage \blindtext \newpage \blindtext
\clearpage
\SetChapterTitleGeometry
\newpage
\LARGE{Testing2}
\par \blindtext

\clearpage
\SetChapterPageGeometry

\blindtext \pagebreak \blindtext \clearpage \blindtext \newpage \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not just looking for `\newgeometry`, are you?

Comment: the shipout hooks are used at a time when the shipout box has already been made, so changing geometry or headers here it not really possibly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: They apply at the next shipout - and shipout is the time when the box has been constructed and tex is ready to ship it out. You can discard the box here, you can also add stuff, theoretically you can also unbox it and rearrange a lot (even more if you are using lualatex), but this quite low-level programming. So better describe your real problem and don't get stuck in your implementation idea.

Comment: sorry your code is simply nonsense, geometry won't do anything here. I don't know what you are trying to achieve and I won't ask again.

Comment: the geometry code will probably (at least the global part) affect later pages, but not the one you want to change, as it is already set. Why don't you use \thispagestyle? that is the right command to set a special page styles.

Comment: the question title is not "how to use atbegshi" (which would be too vage anyway), it is "How to Alternate Geometry Layouts with atbegshi". And the answer here is: don't do it. If you actually want to ask something else, ask a new question. Beside this: don't use everyshi,  it doesn't add any additional feature, use only atbegshi.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I updated the title and showed how omitted geometry properties in the preamble can be changed later.  Why shouldn't you use `\atbegshi` for this? For example, if I want to alternate geometry to change watermark illustrations used in the headers?

Comment: you are confusing concepts. geometry is about page sizes, not about content.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Geometry sets ***placeholders*** for major content areas, (margin notes, footnotes, headers, and footers.  That's all I am trying to do.  I got a response from a friend - and trying it out.

Comment: geometry set lengths, nothing else. These lengths are used in other places, when e.g. tex breaks a paragraph, or the output routine places headers and footer or floats. Changing the lengths after the fact, when tex and the output routine have already done their work, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: To me this seems a very typical beginners question: instead of telling us the real problem, you ask for help with the »solution«. Hey, what is your real use case?